# continuous function on a disconnected domain

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S=[0,1) \cup [2,3]$ and $f:S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly increasing function such that $f(S)$ is connected.

How to prove $f$ must be continuous?

I think $f$  has a Intermediate Value Property but not sure

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general,

if $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ and $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is discontinuous and increasing then we have $f(S)$ is not connected.

*Proof:*

Suppose $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$.

Because $f$ is increasing we have that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+} f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^-} f(x)$ both exist and we have:

$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^-} f(x)\leq f(x_0) \leq \lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+} f(x)$. And one of the inequalities must be strict because of discontinuity.

Suppose that it is the first one, then $(-\infty, \lim\limits_{x\to x_0^-} f(x))$ and $([\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^-} f(x)+f(x_0) ]/2, \infty)$ are two disjoint open sets covering $f(S)$, proving $f(S)$ is disconnected.

The case in which the second inequality is strict is analogous.

Comment: How to compare your result in my problem?  (sorry! i can't understand)

Comment: If $f$ was not continuous we would have that $f(S)$ is not connected.

Comment: I'm confused with your statement " then we have $S$ is not connected"...

Comment: I proved any discontinuous increasing function $f: S\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ satisfies $f(S)$ is disconnected. The contrapositive of this statement is what you want.

Comment: which book contains this type of results? Can you recommend any book please?

Comment: I recommend you learn topology, then you'll be able to think about these sort of things much easier.